# How to add MBProgressHUD while saving the image photolibrary IOS7

Tags: ios, image, download, mbprogresshud

Hi in my application i have the image on `UIImageView` and i have button called download once user click the download button the image will save to the `Photolibrary`. Now i want to add the Progressbar for the download to know the user its downloading the image.

I have used the `MBProgressHUD` for the progress but not able work like i wanted. I want to show once user click the download button like its **downloading message** with progress once image got downloaded i want to show like **image downloaded** please tell me how to achieve this one i tired something like that its not working.

My `MBProgressHUD` code.

```
- (IBAction)down:(id)sender {

   HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
   HUD.labelText = @"downloading...";

   HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
   [self.view addSubview:HUD];

   [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(download) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageview.image, nil, nil, nil);

 }

- (void)download {
float progress = 0.0;

while (progress < 1.0) {
    progress += 0.01;
    HUD.progress = progress;
    usleep(50000);
  }
}
```

I have used the above code to achieve but its not working like i wanted please tell me how to achieve this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)down:(id)sender {



HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
HUD.mode =MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;

NSString *strloadingText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading...."];
HUD.labelText = strloadingText;


[HUD show:YES];

[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(doSomeFunkyStuff) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];



}


- (void)doSomeFunkyStuff {
float progress = 0.0;

while (progress < 1.0) {
    progress += 0.01;
    HUD.progress = progress;

    usleep(5000000);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),
                  ^{
                       // process in background thread
                      NSString *strloadingText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"completed"];
                      HUD.labelText = strloadingText;UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageview.image, nil, nil, nil);




                       [HUD hide:YES];


                   });

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum works on main thread. So, put this function in GCD. Your UI can not update itself when main thread is busy.

Comment: sorry did't get u im new for the ios development so can please tell me what excalty i want to do

Comment: Refer this link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)down:(id)sender {
...

[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(download) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),
^{
        // process in background thread
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageview.image, nil, nil, nil);

        // when finish, dismiss HUD
        HUD.hidden = YES;

 });
}
```

Comment: its showing error in [HUD_code dismiss]; like unused identifier hud_code please tell where to declare this one

Comment: `HUD_code dismiss` just is my example. You should use your code to dismiss this HUD.

Comment: now its not working its not even showing the progagress bar please tell how to resolve this one

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD for showing progress bar..If you are downloading image from server then use async call. Like if you are using  ASIFormDataRequest request for getting image then use as follow :

```
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Please wait"];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"your URL request"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setPostValue:xyz forKey:@"abc"];
    [request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;
    request.delegate=self;
    request.timeOutSeconds = 10;
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

After this you can call :

-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];

```
if (!error)
{

    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [response JSONValue];
     [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
   self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageview.image, nil, nil, nil);
```

}
}

Hope this will help you.